# Linear algebra, projection onto subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If $q_1$ and $q_2$ are any orthonormal vectors in $R^5$, give a formula for the projection $p$ of any vector $b$ onto the plane spanned by $q_1$ and $q_2$.

I used the projection formula $P = A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$ and got $q_1q_1^T + q_2q_2^T$. But solution says it's $q_1^Tbq_1 + q_2^Tbq^2$. I set $A$ as $(q_1 q_2)$ ($q_1,q_2$ are in column form). Did I use the formula wrong?

For reference this is exam 2, 18.06 on MIT OCW

Comment: Your answer doesn't involve b, so it can't be the formula for the projection of b. Try applying your function to b.

Comment: Actually never mind, I think it is correct once applied to b. $q^2$ must be a typo for $q_2$ on the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question means to find the projected image of $b$. Since $q_i^Tb$ is a scalar, $(q_1q_1^T+q_2q_2^T)b=q_1(q_1^Tb)+q_2(q_2^Tb)=(q_1^Tb)q_1+(q_2^Tb)q_2$.

Answer (score 0):

You computed the matrix $P$ that represents this projection, but you were asked to find an expression for the projection of the vector $b$. Multiply $b$ by your matrix and rearrange.